# Subscribe to questions based on list of favorite tags

Tags: support, tags, filtering, newsletter

I know that we can subscribe to specific tags with the help of filters

[image]

However, I have plenty of favorite tags and it would be time-costly to create a filter for each. Can I set up subscription to email so that it cover **all** fav tags **at once**?

Comment: Create a search/filter with all of your tags using the OR operator.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, but maybe it'd be more convenient to add correspondent setting? Can I add this feature request?

Comment: However, it seems that *Favorite tags* filter works as I described by default, so my question is unnecessary.